# How to use App script to run a google big query and save it as a new table which can we reused?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

How to use app script to run a google big query and save the results in a new table in the same project folder on google big query

Comment: Try something, do your best to identify and overcome any issues you run into, then come back here and post questions about specific problems you have not been able to resolve.

Answer (score 5):

It will look like this:

```
function saveQueryToTable() {
  var projectId = 'your project';
  var datasetId = 'your dataset';
  var tableId = 'your table';
  var job = {
    configuration: {
      query: {
        query: 'SELECT TOP(word, 300) AS word, COUNT(*) AS word_count' +
               'FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare' +
               'WHERE LENGTH(word) > 10;',
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: datasetId,
          tableId: tableId
        }
      }
    }
  };

  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId);
  Logger.log(queryResults.status);
}
```

More examples [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery).

Comment: where do I get the tableID from?

Comment: Raghav, it's you who should know where to save the result to ;) If such a table doesn't exist BigQuery will create it.

Comment: Oh its just a name that I want to assign to the table. How about doing multiple table creations one after the other? How do I create lag time between the creation of 2 tables?

Comment: how could I use the sleep utilities function until the tables arent formed

Comment: @RAGHAVRASTOGI Maybe it would be easier for you to use our [add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/owox-bi-bigquery-reports/fepofngogkjnejgcbdmmkddnpeojbbin) Querying and uploading is more simple with interface, parameters and scheduling.